# SharePoint 2010 - Enable farm scope feature via powershell

Tags: powershell, feature-activation

I have deployed a solution with farm scope feature.

I am able to activate / deactivate feature via "Manage Farm feature".

I want to do this via power shell :

When i try to activate feature "Enable-SPFeature -Identity *14hive_featurefoldername* though this command exception is thrown:

**Enable-SPFeature : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Whereas Disable-SPFeature feature work properly.

What am i missing in Enable-SPFeature statement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code in `SPFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated` method is throwing this exception. Please check and correct the code in your Feature Receiver class.

Comment: I also think this is the case. Check the ULS log, it definitely will contain the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to identify the feature by its id (guid). this worked perfectly for me.

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity [Guid]
```

If you don't know the Identity of the feature have a look at the properties in Visual Studio or use SP Manager 2010